# Google charts with two series on charts (SQL/PHP)

Tags: php, sql, database, charts, google-visualization

I trying build the charts with API google charts and i'am very lost... I have a database on PhpMyAdmin where there are 2 columns : numberPeople and date.

So, I would like to display on the chart, the number of people for year N and an other lines with year N-1...

But I don't understand.
Could you help me? I put to you in appendix what I have make

```html
<?php

$pdoSynchro = new PDO("mysql:dbname=store17;host=localhost","root","");

$date_now = date("Y");
$date_old = date("Y")-1;

$anneeN = $pdoSynchro->query('SELECT nombrePersonne, date FROM compteur_client WHERE YEAR(date) ='.$date_now);
$anneeN1 = $pdoSynchro->query('SELECT nombrePersonne, date FROM compteur_client WHERE YEAR(date) ='.$date_old);



$table = array();
$table['cols'] = array(

    // Labels for your chart, these represent the column titles
    // Note that one column is in "string" format and another one is in "number" format as pie chart only required "numbers" for calculating percentage and string will be used for column title
    array('label' => 'Date', 'type' => 'string'),
    array('label' => 'Nbr de personne en '.$date_now, 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'Nbr de personne en '.$date_old, 'type' => 'number')

);

$rows = array();

while ($r = $anneeN->fetch()) {
    $temp = array();
    $temp[] = array('v' => $r['date']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['nombrePersonne']);
    $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
}

$table['rows'] = $rows;
$jsonTable = json_encode($table);


var_dump($jsonTable);
//echo $jsonTable;
?>

<html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the Ajax API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
    google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

   

    function drawChart() 
    {

        
      // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?php echo $jsonTable; ?>);
        var options = {
        title: 'Nombre de clients par jour',
          width: 1000,
          height: 500,
        };



      // Do not forget to check your div ID
      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('linechart_material'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--this is the div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="linechart_material"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```html
<?php

$pdoSynchro = new PDO("mysql:dbname=store17;host=localhost","root","");

$query = $pdoSynchro->query("SELECT date, nombrePersonne FROM compteur_client"); // select column
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Massive Electronics</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart(){
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ['Date','Nombre client par jour'],
                <?php
                    while($row = $query->fetch()){
                        echo "['".$row["date"]."', ".$row["nombrePersonne"]."],";
                    }
                ?>
               ]);

            var options = {
                title: 'Nombre client/J',
                curveType: 'function',
                legend: { position: 'bottom' }
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('areachart'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
     <div id="areachart" style="width: 900px; height: 400px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

For the result of my JSON data ( it's part of data because, not all data is not displayed ) :

```js
'{"cols":[
    {"label":"Date N","type":"string"},
    {"label":"Nbr de personne en 2018","type":"number"},
    {"label":"Nbr de personne en 2017","type":"number"}],
"rows":[
    {"c":[{"v":"2017-07-05 00:00:00.000000"},{"v":null},{"v":10}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"2017-07-21 00:00:00.000000"},{"v":null},{"v":15}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"2017-07-22 00:00:00.000000"},{"v":null},{"v":12}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"2017-07-23 00:00:00.000000"},{"v":null},{"v":13}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"2017-07-19 00:00:00.000000"},{"v":null},{"v":15}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"2017-07-19 00:00:00.000000"}'
```

THANK YOU VERY MUCH FOR YOU'RE HELP 100000x THANK YOU !!!

**EDIT**

[image]

AND RESULT OF JSON :

```js
{"cols":[
   {"label":"Date","type":"date"},
   {"label":"Nbr de personne en 2018","type":"number"},
   {"label":"Nbr de personne en 2017","type":"number"}],
"rows":[
   {"c":[{"v":"Date(2018, -1, , , , )","f":"2017--"},{"v":null},{"v":10}]},
   {"c":[{"v":"Date(2018, -1, , , , )","f":"2017--"},{"v":null},{"v":15}]},
   {"c":[{"v":"Date(2018, -1, , , , )","f":"2017--"},{"v":null},{"v":12}]},
   {"c":[{"v":"Date(2018, -1, , , , )","f":"2017--"},{"v":null},{"v":13}]},
   {"c":[{"v":"Date(2018, -1, , , , )","f":"2017--"},{"v":null},{"v":15}]}'
```

and i have a message : 'a.getTime' is not a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you have two different queries, you'll need to load separate rows for each,
but you still need to populate both columns...

just use `null` in the column not being used in the query,
as such...

```
// old date
while ($r = $anneeN1->fetch()) {
    $temp = array();
    $temp[] = array('v' => $r['date']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => null);
    $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['nombrePersonne']);
    $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
}

// now date
while ($r = $anneeN->fetch()) {
    $temp = array();
    $temp[] = array('v' => $r['date']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['nombrePersonne']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => null);
    $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
}
```

note: probably makes sense to load old first, so dates are in correct order...

**EDIT**

to compare for year over year, first, we will need to use real dates, not strings...

change the first column from `'string'` to `'date'`...

```
    array('label' => 'Date', 'type' => 'date'),
```

here...

```
$table = array();
$table['cols'] = array(
    array('label' => 'Date', 'type' => 'date'),
    array('label' => 'Nbr de personne en '.$date_now, 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'Nbr de personne en '.$date_old, 'type' => 'number')
);
```

next, the dates will need to be in the same year on the x-axis,
so we need to change the old date to the current year.
but, we can use the formatted value to display the real date in the tooltip...

`'v'` = value, `'f'` = formatted value

we can use google's json date string to pass real dates --> `"Date(y, m, d, h, n, s)"`

so in the "old" routine, we create the date using the current year,
and provide the real date in the formatted value,
then format the "now" dates the same way...

```
// old date
while ($r = $anneeN1->fetch()) {
    // value - old date converted to now year
    $rowDate = "Date(".$date_now.", ".((int) date_format($r['date'], 'm') - 1).", ".date_format($r['date'], 'd').", ".date_format($r['date'], 'H').", ".date_format($r['date'], 'i').", ".date_format($r['date'], 's').")";

    // formatted value - real value
    $rowStr = $date_old."-".date_format($r['date'], 'm')."-".date_format($r['date'], 'd');

    $temp = array();
    $temp[] = array('v' => $rowDate, 'f' => $rowStr);  // <-- use formatted value for real date
    $temp[] = array('v' => null);
    $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['nombrePersonne']);
    $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
}

// now date
while ($r = $anneeN->fetch()) {
    $rowDate = "Date(".$date_now.", ".((int) date_format($r['date'], 'm') - 1).", ".date_format($r['date'], 'd').", ".date_format($r['date'], 'H').", ".date_format($r['date'], 'i').", ".date_format($r['date'], 's').")";
    $rowStr = $date_now."-".date_format($r['date'], 'm')."-".date_format($r['date'], 'd');

    $temp = array();
    $temp[] = array('v' => $rowDate, 'f' => $rowStr);
    $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['nombrePersonne']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => null);
    $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
}
```

to show the month abbreviation on the x-axis, add this to your chart options...

```
hAxis: {format: 'MMM'}
```

**EDIT 2**

need to convert date string from query to real date, see --> `$realDate`

```
// old date
while ($r = $anneeN1->fetch()) {
    $realDate = date_create($r['date']);

    // value - old date converted to now year
    $rowDate = "Date(".$date_now.", ".((int) date_format($realDate, 'm') - 1).", ".date_format($realDate, 'd').", ".date_format($realDate, 'H').", ".date_format($realDate, 'i').", ".date_format($realDate, 's').")";

    // formatted value - real value
    $rowStr = $date_old."-".date_format($realDate, 'm')."-".date_format($realDate, 'd');

    $temp = array();
    $temp[] = array('v' => $rowDate, 'f' => $rowStr);
    $temp[] = array('v' => null);
    $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['nombrePersonne']);
    $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
}

// now date
while ($r = $anneeN->fetch()) {
    $realDate = date_create($r['date']);
    $rowDate = "Date(".$date_now.", ".((int) date_format($realDate, 'm') - 1).", ".date_format($realDate, 'd').", ".date_format($realDate, 'H').", ".date_format($realDate, 'i').", ".date_format($realDate, 's').")";
    $rowStr = $date_now."-".date_format($realDate, 'm')."-".date_format($realDate, 'd');

    $temp = array();
    $temp[] = array('v' => $rowDate, 'f' => $rowStr);
    $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['nombrePersonne']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => null);
    $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
}
```

Comment: OH MY GOD YOU ARE JESUS ! Great answer ! I have just a last question ! I would like compared the two years and to see the two curves one with the top of the other, and to see year whether the figures one increased the other or decreased you see what I mean ?

Comment: I have change method, look at... Can you tell me what is the better for my project ? (I have edit my question)

Comment: I would like the data year - 1 for the same period that current year, to compare and  see the evolution ... :/

Comment: Oh thank you, but I have a error EDIT above with picture .

Comment: +1 , Thank you for you answer ! Yes, it's work ! Can I send messages in private for more questions on Google Charts ?